# how to use mediapipe to show 3d objects such as Glasses.obj on a persons face and shirts pants shoes etc on his body

Tags: android, ios, flutter, artificial-intelligence, augmented-reality

I am trying to create a mobile app where a user can augment glasses or other clothing on there body and see what it looks like but the main issue is i can use mediapipe examples on android dont know how to modify them or use 3d objects in android or ios

I have some experience with jetpack compose and swiftui and the examples to me seems like are built with xml layouts and ui kit respectively either way i cant get them how they are doing it.

I have tried python and was partially successful in modifying (sortof) how i use mediapipe but failed to show 3d objects in the cv2 window for obvious reasons

I am a mobile developer using flutter with as i mentioned some experience in swiftui and jetpack and i am new to AR so what will be the best approach to tackle this thanks :)

I will be willing to switch to any other approach with it makes sence other than using mediapipe for example

I tried to use python in the hopes i will be able to make a server eventually that will process the feed out of a phone camera to identify faces and put 3d objects on it and i tried opengl to render but failed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.